# Is there a way to store images locally and sync to cloud storage when device online?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a scenario where user add the images in offline mode. And when user is online the images should sync to Google cloud storage.

I'm trying to implement this scenario with flutter and google cloud storage.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks is advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the Photos added to the app in a Folder on Phone Memory. you can use local encryptions if you like.

then use the https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity to check if the device is online.

then you can hook a task to upload the photos.

Answer (score 0):

First when you pick the images, you would need to either pick an image from Gallery or Camera. For that you can use [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and the code would look like this:

```
final File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
```

After you are done with picking image, File is output object containing your image and path to it stored locally (`image.path`).

If you want to show that local image, you can do it like this:

```
Image.file(File(image.path))
```

And when it comes to uploading, there are multiple examples on how to upload `File` object to any API depending on your REST API preferred library.